# merging 3 lists in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, mergesort

I am wondering how to merge 3 lists into one list.

here is merging two lists

```
 merge :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
 merge xs [] = xs
 merge [] ys = ys
 merge (x:xs) (y:ys) | x <= y    = x:merge xs (y:ys)
                     | otherwise = y:merge (x:xs) ys
```

what should I do if I want to merge three lists ?

Answer (score 8):

Your `merge` function can already merge two lists and since it is a binary associative operation you could do:

```hs
list1 `merge` (list2 `merge` list3)
```

Or more generally if you want to merge an arbitrary number of lists:

```hs
mergeAll :: Ord a => [[a]] -> [a]
mergeAll = foldl merge []
```

Wikipedia has a great explanation on [Folding](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Fold_(higher-order_function)).

Comment: Wow, a rare case where the non-strict `foldl` is reasonable :)

Comment: Yeah, though if strictness becomes a concern they would be probably be using something from `array`  or `containers` rather than linked lists. :P

Comment: @ephemient however it's still no better than `foldr`. BTW this `mergeAll` is asymptotically bad in the case where all the lists are similar length -- better to merge in a tree-like pattern `mergeAll xss = mergeAll (uncurry merge <$> adjacentPairs xss)` (plus appropriate base cases)

Comment: @luqui True, though I meant relative to `foldl'` which is almost always preferred over `foldl`.

Comment: @ephemient, try `head $ foldl merge [] (replicate 5000000 [1,2,3])` versus `foldl'`

Comment: @luqui As the only thing that `foldl'` forces is the list head, there's effectively no difference between `foldl` and `foldl'`. This is contrary to the common case where there *is* a difference, hence my original comment.

Comment: @ephemient did you try?

Comment: @luqui Yes I did.

Comment: @ephemient I observed a timing difference of a factor of 1.5.  And you are also right of course that the list head is the only difference.  But the list head is 5 million thunks deeper for `foldl` than `foldl'`, which does make a pretty substantial difference here. `foldl` still has yet to prove it deserves attention (but I suppose it's getting our attention now by continuing to be crappy).  As you chomp further out in the output list they start getting comparable in timing, as expected.

Comment: @FabiánHerediaMontiel so just add ``` mergeAll :: Ord a => [[a]] -> [a]
mergeAll = foldl merge [] ``` at the end of my code?

Comment: @Meem, that is one way to merge a list of lists, yeah. Though, as mentioned you just need to use your binary operation twice to merge 3 lists.

Comment: @FabiánHerediaMontiel what I understand is repeat the binary operation twice or what?